# git push heroku master is rejected and faild to compile ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, paperclip

Did some research but can't figure out what caused the rejection when I tried to `git push heroku master.`

Here is my the git repo: https://github.com/leonahu/IMGfeed
and this is the details of the rejection:

```
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to feedimg.
remote:
```

Comment: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` - Have you added this to `config/application.rb` ?

Comment: @dkp. I have actually.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the assets failed to precompile, so you should precompile them by running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Or specifically for production run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Make sure that you have this line of code in your `config/application.rb` file: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

After this, try to push to heroku again

Comment: Thank you @luka kerr. I have done all the steps you mentioned, but it is still generating the same error.

Comment: Is that the only error you are getting? If the error is longer, could you edit your question and post the full error log

Comment: Oh and I've just checked out your app on github and saw that you're using sqlite 3 as your database - on heroku this isn't supported. You'll need to change your database to postgres or something else. You can get more details here devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I think you might forget to set `config.secret_key_base` in production. Run:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=your_secret_key_base
```

To get a new secret key you can run `bundle exec rake secret` in the project's root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions above but it did not work on my app ( Thanks everyone who tried to help nevertheless.) 
What ended up working for me is I basically forced the Heroku by running:

```
git push heroku master --force
```

After that, I was able to `git push heroku master` again.